# Eclipse: setting default action for double-clicking files of a certain type

Tags: eclipse, editor

I have .py and .js files in my Eclipse project for various reasons, but I don't ever want to execute them by double-clicking on them in Eclipse -- which is the default Eclipse behavior.

Is there a way I can change this default behavior so it just opens files in the Eclipse text editor, rather than executes the system "Open" command?

Comment: I'm afraid it would take a few hours, this might be helpful http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/actions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the main Preferences window and go to

```
General->Editors->File Associations
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, On the menu bar at the top, go to

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations
```

Set the `Open unassociated files with` to `Text Editor`

This opens your files with the Eclipse text editor on double click.

[image]

[image]